# I am not able to load the string value consists of " , / from .csv into SQL using ADF v2

Tags: sql, json, azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I have a .CSV file wanted to load into SQL using Azure data factory V2. One of the column string value as (Hi there" how,are /you) but i am not able to load this record with string when it has " , / in to sql.

Escape Character /(Backslash)
Quote Character  "(double quotes)
Column delimiter .(coma)

Want to pass the record when the string like below into sql table.
Column1
Hi there" how,are /you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way is that you need to edit the csv file, then you can load this data into the sql table in Data Factory.

You need change your csv data follow this document: [Text format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#text-format):
[image]

> **Note:** **You cannot specify both escapeChar and quoteChar for a table.**

So you should change the column1 data like this, add Escape Character "\" before ",are/you":

```
Hi there"how\,are/you
```

And don't set the Quote Character.

[image]

**Update:**

This the test2.csv file in my Blob Storage:
[image]

Source dataset setting in pipline:

1. **Column delimeiter**: comma(,)
2. **Row delimiter**: Auto detect (\r,\n, or \r\n)
3. **Escape character**: Backslash ()
4. **Quote Character**: No quote character

Source dataset json code:

```
{
    "name": "DelimitedText1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": "test2.csv",
                "container": "containerleon"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": false,
            "quoteChar": ""
        },
        "schema": [
            {
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Yue, thanks for your time and sharing me the details. I tried these steps but i dont have luck. I will share you my screen shots.

Comment: I used the same set of properties but unfortunately its not working for me. I cannot change the input code. Below is my sample input string which i am having issue.
Input below                                                                                                                   
Day Try.SMF 9" 1.0pp,5/MN

Comment: @user11894930 My file also saved in my Azure blob storage. I can't see  your screenshot. I can show you more details.

Comment: I tried the option Quote character as none in the Connection properties of a blob linked service and no luck.

Comment: Hi @user11894930, If you could not change the column1 data to `Hi there"how\,are/you` in csv file in your blob storage,  all the settings in Data Factory will not works. You can edit the csv file in blog storage, if you have the permission. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: But there will be tons of data coming from excel where i am storing in blob.This will be hard to update each record.

Comment: Yeah, that's a real big problem. How about use the replace all in you excel?